# Property reflection in Objective C for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to be able to use reflection on a classes within Objective C to determine what properties are available at run time.

I do something similar for classes right now using

```
NSString *str = NSStringFromClass([object class]);
```

What I would like to do is use this result to go back to the class and see what properties are available as well as what type these properties are.

Comment: why do you not use protocols to make sure the actual property / method is available in runtime for certain objects?

Comment: Properties are determined at runtime based on the database schema so a dynamic method call is less code and more flexible for my particular use case. Also; it is interesting how you down vote me even though you have absolutely no idea what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: no hard feelings. I highly doubt your database is such "dynamic" and that'd be the only and omnipotent solution.

Comment: Like I said; you have no idea the context of what I was doing at the time.  I was not building a one use data access layer.  I created a drop in object relational mapper for use with SQLite.  It is essentially ActiveRecord for iOS.  This then allows automatic access to any table for what we consider to be "most-likely" needed behavior.  If the developer needs something above and beyond than they are able to override behavior by defining a protocol only when it is actually needed. This saved us 3 months of work on the first project we used it on; that included time to build the library itself.

Comment: good luck with your project!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

May be this will help:

You can get the list of properties in a class using class_copyPropertyList

```
objc_property_t * class_copyPropertyList(Class cls, unsigned int *outCount)
```

and then from each property, you can get the property name using `property_getName` function and the property attributes using the `property_getAttributes` function (if you need to filter read-write properties).

Comment: Check out the [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW24) and the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the answer to my direct question, but also to the extremely informative guides that provided a lot of additional information I was wanting as well.